# More Efficient Way of Calculating Population from Data Grid and overlapping Polygon?

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, postgis, quadtree, population

folks!  Apologies if this is a duplicate question and I've done some research on the topic but don't know if I'm heading in the right direction.

I have converted gridded data of population density to a MongoDB collection using a geometry object defining the population density cell as a five node polygon (the fifth node matching the first) and a float value consisting of the population in that geographic region.  Even though the database is huge in size, I can quickly retrieve the "records" of the population regions as they are indexed as a 2D Sphere when it intersects a geo-polygon indicating some type of weather event or other geofence polygon.

The issue comes when I try to add all of the boxes up.  It takes an exceedingly long amount of time, especially if the polygon is of a significant geographic area.  The population data I have are 1km^2 cells.  The adding of the data can take several seconds or, in worse case scenario, minutes!

I had a thought of creating a type of quadtree structure in the database by a lower resolution node set as a separate collection and so on and so on.  Then when calculating population, I could start with the lowest res set and work my way down the node "tree" by making several database calls until there are no more matches.  While I'd increase my database calls significantly, I'd reduce the sheer number of elements that I would need to add up at the end - which is taking the most computational time.

I could try to create these data using bottom-up neighbor finding whilst adding up the four population values that would make up the next lower-resolution node set.  This, of course, will explode the database size and will increase the number of queries to the database for a single population request.

I haven't seen too much of this done with databases.  I'd like to have it in a database (could also be PostgreSQL) since it gives me the ability to quickly geo-query by point or area.  And, I'm returning the result as an API call so the efficiency of time is of the essence!

Any advice or places to research would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: I dropped the generic "algorithm" tag and added "postgis".  You may want to consider posting to the GIS stackexchange:  https://gis.stackexchange.com/

Comment: As @MikeOrganek suggests, GISs are meant to solve exactly these kinds of problems.  Queries for data within a polygon (which you hint but never state is the operation you're trying to do) are a basic GIS operation. See for example https://postgis.net/ , but note I don't have any personal experience with it.  Asking on the GIS stackexchange is great advice.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions!  With PostGIS I'd need to switch to PostgreSQL from MongoDB.  This isn't a deal breaker but would require some time and effort to maintain another database.  Thanks again for the insight!